# Gitignore Regex for numbers in a certain location

Tags: gitignore

Is there a .gitignore expression that would ignore this...

- Lorem.amet.432.exe

But lets these through?...

- Lorem.432.amet.exe
- 432.Lorem.amet.exe

I tried `*.[0-9].exe`, but doesn't seem to work

Comment: `*.[0-9][0-9][0-9].exe` mighr work if you want to match 3 digits. (Can't try myself right now)

Answer (score 0):

Your try is very close to the right solution!

But here the explanation why only *very close*:

Your default file name (*…432…*) where should be ignored, has 3 numbers. So you must also add the part of `[0-9]` three times and not only once:

```
*.[0-9][0-9][0-9].exe
```

If the part before the three digits is also stable for ignored files, you can further restrict:

If this are only lowercase letters, add `[a-z]` as often as it should have letters. If there should be only capital letters write `[A-Z]` and if both can occur, add this`[a-zA-Z]`.